# C++: template function with explicitly specified reference type as type parameter

Tags: c++, function-templates

I was playing with C++ template type deduction and managed to compile this little program.

```
template<typename T>
 void f(const T& val)
 {
   val = 1;
 }


 int main()
 {
    int i = 0;
    f<int&>(i);
 }
```

It compiles on all major compilers but I do not understand why. Why can `f` assign to `val`, when `val` is explicitly marked `const`? Is it bug in these compilers or is it valid behavior according to the C++ standard?

Comment: Reference collapsing.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ That doesn't seem right to me. An lvalue reference to an lvalue reference is an lvalue reference, not an rvalue reference, so it should expand to `void f(const int&)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

§8.3.2 [dcl.ref]/p6:

> If a *typedef-name* (7.1.3, 14.1)<sup>*</sup> or a *decltype-specifier* (7.1.6.2)
>   denotes a type TR that is a reference to a type T, an attempt to
>   create the type “lvalue reference to cv TR” creates the type “lvalue
>   reference to T”, while an attempt to create the type “rvalue reference
>   to cv TR” creates the type TR.

This is known as *reference collapsing* and is introduced in C++11. In C++03, your code would be ill-formed, but some compilers supported it as an extension.

Note that in `const T &`, the `const` applies to the type `T`, so when `T` is `int &`, the `const` would apply to the reference type itself (which is meaningless as references are immutable anyway), not the type referred to. This is why the reference collapsing specification ignores any cv-qualifiers on `TR`.

---

<sub><sup>*</sup>A template type parameter is a *typedef-name*, per §14.1 [temp.param]/p3:</sub>

> A *type-parameter* whose identifier does not follow an ellipsis
>   defines its *identifier* to be a *typedef-name* (if declared with
>   `class` or `typename`) or *template-name* (if declared with
>   `template`) in the scope of the template declaration.

Comment: I thought this was a very good answer, direct and without mystification. (+1)

Answer (score 2):

I would like to append other posts with the following quote from the C++ Standard (8.3.2 References)

> 1... Cv-qualified references are ill-formed except when the cv-qualifiers are introduced through the use of a typedef-name (7.1.3,
>   14.1) or decltype-specificer (7.1.6.2), in which case the **cv-qualifiers are ignored.**

```
[ Example:
typedef int& A;
const A aref = 3; // ill-formed; lvalue reference to non-const initialized with rvalue
```

In the example above from the C++ Standard the last statement will not be compiled because qualifier const is ignored (according to the quote) and you may not bind rvalue with a non-const reference.

Comment: This seems to be the relevant quote.

Comment: The "ignoring cv-qualifier" part is embedded into the specification for reference collapsing and doesn't require the extra paragraph you cited. Note the "cv TR" part.

Comment: @T.C. I could say in turn that the part of specification for reference collapsing relative to cv-qualifiers is described in the quote I cited. So there is ni need in extra paragraph you referenced to because the question in essence about cv-qualifiers of references that are template arguments.

Answer (score 1):

`const T&` does not turn into `int&` in this example: in `f<int&>(i)`, you are explicitly setting `T` to `int&`. `const` only enters the picture when that definition of `T` is used to determine the type of `val`, which becomes `const int&` (one subtlety there is that references are collapsed during this substitution, so you don't wind up with two `&`'s in the type).

Comment: Maybe I'm misreading your answer, but does that explain how the assignment to `const` is possible?

Comment: Oh, no, it doesn't; I missed that aspect of the question.