# Why does the const in a const T& parameter disappear when T is a reference type?

Tags: c++, templates, type-deduction

The following code shows that if a template taking a ref-to-`const` parameter is instantiated with a reference type (e.g., `int&`), the parameter isn't `const`:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
void f(const T& arg)         // arg isn't const if T is a reference type
{
  arg = -1;
}

int main()
{
  int x = 0;
  f<int&>(x);                // instantiate f with reference type
  std::cout << x << '\n';    // prints -1 under gcc, clang, and msvc
}
```

What's going on here?

My guess is that the initial type of `arg` is `int & const &` and that this somehow transforms to `int&`. If that's so, exactly how does that happen, in terms of the standard? If that's not what's going on, what is?

Comment: Related to [c98-03-reference-collapsing-and-cv-qualifiers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14761581/c98-03-reference-collapsing-and-cv-qualifiers)

Comment: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS2LWA_12.1.0/com.ibm.xlcpp121.bg.doc/language_ref/reference_collapsing.html has 2 tables for Reference collapsing.

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Reference collapsing?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3771208)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27256516/c-template-function-with-explicitly-specified-reference-type-as-type-paramete/27256623#27256623

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to [Vlad from Moscow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2877241/vlad-from-moscow)'s answer to [C++: template function with explicitly specified reference type as type parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27256516/c-template-function-with-explicitly-specified-reference-type-as-type-parameter), I believe the crux of the `const`-disappearance is [dcl.ref], which says:

> In a declaration `T D` where `D` has either of the forms
>
> > & *attribute-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub>* D1 
> > && *attribute-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub>* D1
>
> and the type of the identifier in the declaration `T D1` is
> “*derived-declarator-type-list* `T`”, then the type of the identifier of `D`
> is “*derived-declarator-type-list* reference to `T`.” The optional
> *attribute-specifier-seq* appertains to the reference type. Cv-qualified
> references are ill-formed except when the cv-qualifiers are introduced
> through the use of a *typedef-name* ([dcl.typedef], [temp.param]) or *decltype-specifier*
> ([dcl.type.simple]), **in which case the cv-qualifiers are ignored**.

I've emboldened the relevant text. (I'd like to format the entire paragraph as it is in the standard, but I can't figure out how to get the right indentation and to add subscripting.)

Once the `const` disappears, normal reference collapsing kicks in as usual.

Comment: This seems to be the correct answer. Note that in http://stackoverflow.com/a/14761809/777186, Yakk derived it from 8.3.2/5 (which used to be 14.3.2/4 in pre-release versions of C++11).

Answer (score 3):

A `const T` is a object of type `T` whose value cannot be modified. However, when `T` is a reference type, the `const` modifier is superfluous since references cannot be changed once initialized - they always refer to the same object. Thus, a `const T` when `T=int&` is just a `T`(which in this case is `int&`). Thus, the argument that `f<int&>` takes is a lvalue reference to an `int&`, which by c++11's collapsing rules is just `int&`.

Comment: Can you give some guidance about where in the standard this behavior is specified, i.e., where it says that const T is T when T is a reference type?