# Reference collapsing and const

Tags: c++, c++14, type-deduction

Consider this program:

```
template<typename T>
struct Foo
{
    void foo(const T&) {}   
    void foo(T&) {}
};


int main()
{
    Foo<double&> f;   
    double d = 3.14;
    f.foo(d);   //complains that foo() is ambigous
}
```

In the above, if Foo is instantiated as `Foo<double>` , then things are fine, but if it is instantiated as `Foo<double&>`, then the call to `foo` becomes ambiguous. Is ref collapsing at play here when deducing the param types for `foo` and if so why is constness being ignored?

Comment: What do you mean with `const`ness being ignored? Where do you use that `const`ness ?

Comment: Ok, I found the answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/27728034/150365

Comment: @bolov The duplicate doesn't seem to relate. Since, in that case the OP refers to a function template and not a class template.

Comment: @101010 yes, but the same rules/principles apply. Anyway, I don't know what happened, I see now the question is closed by T.C.

Answer (score 3):

Lets see what happens if we try to instatiate the `Foo` class template:

```
template<typename T>
struct Foo {
  void foo(T const&) {}   
  void foo(T&) {}
};
```

with template parameter `double&`. Substituting T with `double&` and according to reference collapsing rules you would get:

```
struct Foo {
  void foo(double& const) {}   
  void foo(double&) {}
};
```

Since references are inherently constant `double& const` is equivalent to `double&`. Thus, you get the following instatiation:

```
struct Foo {
  void foo(double&) {}   
  void foo(double&) {}
};
```

Here comes the compiler shouting "Dude you can't overload `foo` with the same signature".

A more consise error is given by CLANG:

> error: multiple overloads of 'foo' instantiate to the same signature
>   'void (double &&)'   void foo(T&) { }

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2e9a05deacdd8e2c)

Comment: `double&`, not `double&&`